# How to implement authentication system using SAML2 and OAuth2

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, sap, saml-2.0

I am having a requirement to use SAML2.0 with oAuth2 to authenticate a user. 
where the User will use resource provider like SAP/Office365/etc...

1) My question is do I need to create my own IDP?
2) and If I am using my IDP where the list of my user are in some Database will that work?

I just basic message flow of in SAML OAuth implementation.

Any help is appreciated.

Tech stack I am using is (.Net c#) Azure

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

SAML and OAuth (with OpenID Connect) are completely different protocols.

If you are using Azure, you need two client side stacks, one for each protocol.

You can do this with OWIN : [OWIN : ASP.NET MVC application with multiple authentication options](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/01/owin-adpnet-mvc-application-with.html) .